# Not able to preview document with extension doc,ppt in alfresco

Tags: liferay-6, alfresco, alfresco-share

Having issue while previewing document in alfresco share.
Pdf ,and image file successfully preview.
But problem with docx, and pptx file..couldn't preview in alfresco share..
Got following error

```
Alfresco    Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error

The Web Script /alfresco/wcs/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/39ca1cfb-58ae-49e7-8ef9-9a3bcd0f27bb/content/thumbnails/webpreview has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:    An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Message:    10100005 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10100103 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js': 10100102 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2015/11/10/13/15/df0306de-c378-48f6-9815-66966bb9c8dc.bin, mimetype=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, size=306210, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2015/11/10/13/20/d6055d8b-48ae-432a-8658-b9b16afd862e.bin, mimetype=application/x-shockwave-flash, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US] options: {targetContentProperty=null, contentReaderNodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/39ca1cfb-58ae-49e7-8ef9-9a3bcd0f27bb, contentWriterNodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/08ecd5ae-58b7-439a-8450-7db3e1ba45c5, sourceContentProperty=null, use=webpreview, includeEmbedded=false} limits: {maxSourceSizeKBytes=4096}
```

I also checked log file..
In log file I got following error

```
     ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-8080-exec-12] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 10100003 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10100091 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js': 10100090 Content conversion failed: 
   reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2015/11/10/13/15/df0306de-c378-48f6-9815-66966bb9c8dc.bin, mimetype=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, size=306210, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
   writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2015/11/10/13/18/3e665fd1-1789-43c9-92a0-6d30ff2a1b87.bin, mimetype=application/x-shockwave-flash, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
   options: {targetContentProperty=null, contentReaderNodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/39ca1cfb-58ae-49e7-8ef9-9a3bcd0f27bb, contentWriterNodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/0b38853c-3e2a-4526-91bc-22f852c38506, sourceContentProperty=null, use=webpreview, includeEmbedded=false}
   limits: {maxSourceSizeKBytes=4096}
 org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 10100003 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10100091 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js': 10100090 Content conversion failed: 
   reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2015/11/10/13/15/df0306de-c378-48f6-9815-66966bb9c8dc.bin, mimetype=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, size=306210, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
   writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2015/11/10/13/18/3e665fd1-1789-43c9-92a0-6d30ff2a1b87.bin, mimetype=application/x-shockwave-flash, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
   options: {targetContentProperty=null, contentReaderNodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/39ca1cfb-58ae-49e7-8ef9-9a3bcd0f27bb, contentWriterNodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/0b38853c-3e2a-4526-91bc-22f852c38506, sourceContentProperty=null, use=webpreview, includeEmbedded=false}
   limits: {maxSourceSizeKBytes=4096}
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.content.StreamContent.execute(StreamContent.java:184)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:429)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:341)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor509.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:125)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy329.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor509.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy329.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor509.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:125)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy329.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

openoffice error

```
  from file: /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/OpenOfficeContentTransformer-source-2887837723322448158.doc
   to file: /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/OpenOfficeContentTransformer-target-996640461019588441.pdf
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.OOoContentTransformerHelper.transform(OOoContentTransformerHelper.java:372)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor850.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer.transformInternal(ProxyContentTransformer.java:98)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:211)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: net.sf.jooreports.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed; java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at net.sf.jooreports.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:117)
    at net.sf.jooreports.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:88)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.OpenOfficeContentTransformerWorker.convert(OpenOfficeContentTransformerWorker.java:118)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.OOoContentTransformerHelper.transform(OOoContentTransformerHelper.java:368)
```

alfresco-global.properties

```
ooo.exe=/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=8100
img.root=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/common
img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
img.exe=${img.root}/bin/convert
swf.exe=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/common/bin/pdf2swf
swf.languagedir=/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/common/japanese
img.gslib=${img.root}/share/ghostscript/8.56/lib

jodconverter.enabled=true
jodconverter.officeHome=/usr/lib/libreoffice
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100
```

I am using alfresco 4.2.f

How can I solve this problem
Please help
Thank you

Comment: Do you have OpenOffice / LibreOffice / JODConverter correctly installed and configured on your machine?

Comment: yes...In global.properties file also mention..check once I update qu

Comment: Are those the correct details? Have you verified that Alfresco can successfully connect using them?

Answer (score 1):

Did you touch the Transformer configuration?
Alfresco has a more or less a senseless default config by limiting  office doc max sizes. In your stacktrace I see a max of 8 MB

You need to overwrite the transformer config by copying transformers.properties and transformers-context.xml to tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Transformers/default/default and change values as required.
e.g.

```
content.transformer.complex.OpenOffice.Pdf2swf.extensions.pptx.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=20480
```

btw: jodconverter is no longer available in community edition so you can remove the parameters from your alfresco-global.properties

Comment: Thanks for reply..I tried your solution but it didn't work..Got same error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed the necesarry dependency libs in your OS (and in correct 32 or 64 bit version) http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/install-lolibfiles.html :

1. centos

> yum install libXrender libSM libICE libXext fontconfig cups-libs
>   dbus-glib.x86_64 libXt.x86_64

2. ubuntu

> apt-get install libice6 libsm6 libxt6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1
>   libcups2

Comment: I tried your solution..When I install mention library then got following libice6 is already the newest version.
libsm6 is already the newest version.
libxt6 is already the newest version.
libxt6 set to manually installed.
libcups2 is already the newest version.
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version.
libxrender1 is already the newest version. But can not preview doc , ppt, docx, pptx file

Answer (score 0):

Could you try making the following changes(assuming alfresco is installed in /opt/alfresco-4.2.f) :

vi  /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/alfresco.sh:
=> LIBREOFFICE_SCRIPT=$INSTALLDIR/libreoffice/scripts/**libreoffice_ctl.sh**

vi /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/libreoffice/program/sofficerc 
=>change  Logo=1 to **Logo=0**.